# INFO Configuration deprecation session id is deprecated Instead use dfs metrics session-id

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set up hadoop 2.6.2. Almost everything has been setup.

My Ubuntu version: 15.10
My hadoop path is /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.2
Java path is /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65

I have mentioned java and hadoop path in /etc/profile

I have edited 4 files inside hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop: core-site.xml, hadoop-env.sh, hdfs-site.xml and mapred-site.xml

But when I try to execute following command from hadoop site

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.2.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

Then it gives me following error

```
 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
15/11/25 07:57:09 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
java.net.ConnectException: Call From jass-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: The deprecation log message is just a INFO. The real problem seems to be: "Call From jass-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception". Check if the daemon is running on port 9000.

Comment: I Used sbin/start-dfs.sh for this and made progress. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
I have solved it with following commands:

```
sbin/stop-dfs.sh
bin/hdfs namenode -format
sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

The first command will stop all daemons.
The second will format file system.
The third will start all daemons again.